# NoMethodError (undefined method `address=' for #<Upload:0x007f8b13194b50>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, file-upload, amazon-s3

I'm working on an application where the users can upload pictures from their hard drive. I am saving those pictures to Amazon S3 using paperclip. I'm also saving each picture's Longitude and Latitude of the place from were the user uploads the picture. I'm doing that with geocoder. Everything was working well and since the last time I tried uploading a new picture it is throwing me back the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `address=' for #<Upload:0x007f8b13194b50>):
  app/controllers/uploads_controller.rb:16:in`create'

I can't find the problem, I'm attaching the controller and model that I am using for that.

Controller

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController

  def index

    @uploads = Upload.near([request.location.latitude,    request.location.longitude], 1)

    # render json: Upload.all.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
    render json: @uploads.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
  end

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.create(upload_params)
    if @upload.save
      render json: { message: "success" }, :status => 200
    else
      #need to send an error header, otherwise Dropzone
      #  will not interpret the response as an error:
      render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end         
  end

  private
  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:image, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
end
```

Model

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    # geocoded_by :ip_address,
    # :latitude => :lat, :longitude => :lon
    # after_validation :geocode

    # geocoded_by :address
    # after_validation :geocode

    reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
    after_validation :reverse_geocode  # auto-fetch address

    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",:thumb => "100x100>" }

    validates_attachment    :image, 
                :presence => true,
                :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
                :size => { :less_than => 2.megabyte }

    def image_url
    image.url
    end
end
```

Comment: Somewhere you are trying to save something to an `address` attribute in the Upload class (your error is saying that there is no address setter function).  Without knowing anything about geocoder, was this line `gecoded_by :address` something you recently commented out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to restart your Rails server, or perhaps you've not actually pasted the code you're running.

Line 16 of your controller is the `Upload.create(upload_params)` line, and based on the `geocoded_by :address` code you have commented out in you model I'm guessing that at some point you had `:address` as one of your permitted upload params, and if that was still in `upload_params` and your form then that would explain why `address=` is being called inside the `Upload.create`